# Altering the date when displaying data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

I am working with a severely large SQL Server database and it's `Date` column is designed to be displayed as such:

```
Date(numeric(17,9), not null):

20130623.143448060
```

REQUIRED OUTPUT

That same `Date` translates to:

```
6/23/2013 10:34:48 AM
```

My Current Query is:

```
  SELECT ItemId, Date, Object, SourceSite, DestSite FROM JnlMediumMove WHERE UserCode = 'Automation' AND LEFT(Date,8)=CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE()-1,112) Order By Date Desc;
```

All the dates under the Date column that is displayed in this query is what needs to be altered to the required Output.  I just have two requirements, 1) UserCode is Automation and 2) Only the entries that were inputted 1 day before the current day are displayed.  (Only interested in those entries otherwise too many outputs are displayed)

I was wondering if there is a SQL query which will turn that `Date` into the format of the required output?

Comment: Which db? SQL Server/Oracle/MySQL?

Comment: @shahkalpesh SQL Server

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: Do you mean that the date need to be translated as `6/23/2013 14:34:48 AM`?, why the difference on the time?. Do you need a date datatype as a result, or just format your result that way?

Comment: I have no idea why the time difference is occurring it might be because it's in a different time zone. However right now I'm just lookin for a query to display that specific time and I will try to apply it on all the other dates as well

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) - you should **not** store dates as strings or numbers - you're just asking for trouble that way. Use the `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatypes!

Comment: I know @marc_s unfortunately this was done before my time.  Now I must deal with this headache.

Comment: @omarK I mean that the time on your numeric date is: `143448060` and you want to translate it as `10:34:48 AM`, is that 4 hour difference what you really want?

Comment: @Lamak Yes that 4 hour difference and the changing of the date format is what I'm looking for, Is it possible to have a query for this?

Comment: And can you answer what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @Lamak I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As many comments said, it's a bad idea to store dates this way. Nevertheless, here is one way to cast your numeric value to a `DATETIME` one:

```
DECLARE @Date NUMERIC(17,9)

SET @Date = 20130623.143448060

SELECT  DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(YourDate,8)+' '+
                        SUBSTRING(YourDate,10,2)+':'+
                        SUBSTRING(YourDate,12,2)+':'+
                        SUBSTRING(YourDate,14,2)+'.'+
                        SUBSTRING(YourDate,15,3))) YourDate
FROM (  SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(18),@Date) YourDate) A
```

Result:

```
╔═════════════════════════╗
║        YourDate         ║
╠═════════════════════════╣
║ 2013-06-23 10:34:48.807 ║
╚═════════════════════════╝
```

From here, you can format that date as you please.

**UPDATED**

If you need to use this transformation on the `Date` column, then just use:

```
SELECT  ItemId,
        DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
                        SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
                        SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
                        SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
                        SUBSTRING([Date],15,3))) [Date],
        [Object], 
        SourceSite, 
        DestSite
FROM (  SELECT  ItemId,
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(18),[Date]) [Date],
                [Object],
                SourceSite,
                DestSite,
                            UserCode
        FROM JnlMediumMove) A
WHERE UserCode = 'Automation' 
AND LEFT([Date],8)=CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE()-1,112) 
ORDER BY [Date] DESC;
```

Comment: Alright so this works for that specific date, now how would I apply this to all the dates in the Date column?

Comment: Pardon my lack of knowledge, I'm still a learning programmer.

Comment: I want to incorporate this SQL Query with the code you have just suggested:

SELECT ItemId, Date, Object, SourceSite, DestSite FROM JnlMediumMove WHERE UserCode = 'Automation' AND     
LEFT(Date,8)=CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE()-1,112)
Order By Date Desc;

How would the syntax look like?

Comment: @omarK The example I used was for one variable, you need to apply the same for your column, I don't really understand your issue. And your question on the second comment doesn't seems like the same question asked before. So, instead of using `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(18),@Date) YourDate`, use your real column

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify my problem. I appreciate your patience, is there anyway you can show me how to incorporate your logic into my existing query? I'm still a little confused.

Comment: @omarK So, now you **don't** need the time part?, just the date?

Comment: I have provided you with the appropriate table name and column names as well.

Comment: These are the dates that come up 
20130623.205456927
20130621.204040613
20130624.172943773

@Lamak I am Only interested in the June 23rd one as it is one day before the current day.  And I want all the June 23rd entries to be displayed in this format: 2013-06-23 10:34:48.807.  I hope I have made this easier for you to understand.

Comment: So each day a report is generated consisting of all the entries from the day before with that time format making it easier for the user to understand.

Comment: it gives me this error: Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Argument data type numeric is invalid for argument 1 of substring function.

Comment: @omarK Yeah, that's why I was casting it to a `VARCHAR` on my original answer. Updated again

Comment: Details on Each Key: 1)ItemID(PK, int, notnull) 2)Date(numeric(17,9), not null) 3)Object(nvarchar(128), not null) 4)SourceSite(nvarchar(128), null) 5)DestSite(nvarchar(128), null)

Comment: @omarK Did you test the answer now?

Comment: Now the error is: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
Invalid column name 'UserCode'.  There is no way this is in invalid column name ..

Comment: @omarK Not to be rude or anything, but that was as simple as to add that column on the derived table. Please try again now.

Comment: Ok this is running now, one last problem is that 80% of the entries are of June 23rd and there are a few that are June 22 for some reason.

Comment: Where as all of them must be June 23rd.  Thanks again, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @omarK Well, I'm not really gonna add more to the current answer, since it wasn't what was first asked, and I invested far too much time on this. Please feel free to ask either another question or try to get the current results using the new `[Date]` columns (which is now a `DATETIME`, so it should be easy to handle)

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your help, that is the last thing that I'm stuck on.  I will post another question if you're too busy.

Comment: It gives me this error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.  When I try to get the date of 1 day prior to the current day.

Comment: Hi @Lamak I'm having some problems with an SQL Query that noone can help me with.  is it possible for you to set up a chat for some quick assistance if you're not busy? That would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @omarK I don't really think I can slack work enough to be on a chat room giving you help. For what it's worth, there are far better and experienced on SQL guys on SO, so if you ask a question, you are most likely gonna get an answer. If you want, you can ask the question and link it here for me to try to help you